# Converting xml into php

Tags: php, xml, rest, gdata-api, google-docs

I need help in converting the following xml into php. Anyone can help me?

```
PUT /feeds/default/private/full/resource_id/revisions/revision_number

Host: docs.google.com
GData-Version: 3.0
Authorization: <your authorization header here>
Content-Length: 722
Content-Type: application/atom+xml

<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'xmlns:docs="http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007" gd:etag="W/"DkIBR3st7ImA9WxNbF0o."">
 <id>https://docs.google.com/feeds/id/resource_id/revisions/1</id>
 <updated>2009-08-17T04:22:10.440Z</updated>
 <app:edited xmlns:app="http://www.w3.or /2007/app">2009-08-06T03:25:07.799Z</app:edited>
 <title>Revision 1</title>
 <content type="text/html" src="https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/document/ Export?docId=doc_id&amp;revision=1"/>
 <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="https://docs.google.com/Doc?id=doc_id&amp;revision=1"/>
 <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/resource_id/revisions/1"/>
 <author>
  <name>user</name>
  <email>user@gmail.com</email>
 </author>
 <docs:publish value="true"/>
 <docs:publishAuto value="false"/>
</entry>
```

Comment: You want to parse it with PHP?

Comment: I think he wants to do the PUT request with PHP...?

Comment: ya... and apparently, i duno how to do it for <docs:publish value="true"/>

Comment: **Welcome to StackOverflow!** Please [read the site FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [this guide on how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).  Your question isn't answerable as you've asked it.

Comment: Was that a "ya" to trying to parse it or trying to prepare an XML put request with PHP? IF youre trying to parse it please post the code youre using and a description of the actual problem youre having with the `docs:publish` node.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at standard PHP class simpleXML: [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

The examples there should help you figure it out.

Comment: except for when he runs into "namespace confusion" :-)

Answer (score 0):

> how about for  any idea how to do for
>   this portion?

You want the value of an attribute, not the tag (which is empty). You can access attributes with array syntax for example:

`echo $docsnode['value'];`

or you can use the `attributes` method like:

```
$attrs = $docsnode->attributes();
echo $attrs['value'];
```

And the namespace confusion sets in ;-)

> so am i right to say that for
>   `<docs:publish value="true"/>` `echo
>   $docs['publish']`

Nope thats a namespace elemtn you have to get at those using the `children` method or with xpath (unless they are in the default document namespace, but these nodes arent)...

```
$ns = $xml->getNamespaces();
$docs = $xml->children($ns['docs']);
echo $docs->publish['value'];
echo $docs->publishAuto['value'];
```

OR

```
$docs = $xml->xpath('//docs:*');
echo $docs->publish['value'];
echo $docs->publishAuto['value'];
```

So your code should look something like this:

```
$ns = $feed->getNamespaces();

foreach($feed->entries as $entry)
{
  $docs = $entry->children($ns['docs']);
  $result = $docs->publish['value'];
}
```

Comment: so am i right to say that for <docs:publish value="true"/>
`echo $docs['publish']`

Comment: No... thats not correct `publish` is not an attribute its a tag with the namespace `docs`

Comment: if i need a true value `$docs->publish['value'] = "true"`? @prodigitalson: thanks alot for your help. =)

Comment: If you need to actually set the value in the XML then that would depend on what the other end is expecting... i would say your safeest bet is to use `"true"` as a string... if you use the native boolean values they will be converted to `1/0` at some point. If you need a boolean value in PHP then youll need to manually evaluate the string like `$result = ($docs->publish['value'] == 'true');` or similar

Comment: I try putting these codes inside, but apparently it doesnt work... <br/>`foreach ($feed->entries as $entry){$test = $entry->getNamespaces();$test = $entry->xpath('//docs:*');$result = $test->publish['value'];`